# Ответ на задание не соответствует моему, в чем ошибка?

Tags: excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание:

> Два игрока, Петя и Ваня, играют в следующую игру. Перед игроками лежат две кучи камней. Игроки ходят по очереди, первый ход делает Петя.
> За один ход игрок может убрать из одной из куч один камень или уменьшить количество камней в куче в два раза (если количество камней в куче нечётно, остаётся на 1 камень больше, чем убирается).

> Например, пусть в одной куче 6, а в другой 9 камней; такую позицию мы будем обозначать (6, 9). За один ход из позиции (6, 9) можно получить любую из четырёх позиций: (5, 9), (3, 9), (6, 8), (6, 5).
> Игра завершается в тот момент, когда суммарное количество камней в кучах становится не более 20. Победителем считается игрок, сделавший последний ход, то есть первым получивший позицию, в которой в кучах будет 20 или меньше камней. В начальный момент в первой куче было 10 камней, во второй куче – S камней, S > 10.

> Найдите минимальное и максимальное значение S(Это B5), при котором у Пети есть выигрышная стратегия, причём одновременно выполняются два условия:
> − Петя не может выиграть за один ход;
> − Петя может выиграть своим вторым ходом независимо от того, как будет ходить Ваня.
> Найденные значения запишите в ответе в порядке возрастания.

Получается, что B5 в ответах на задание должен быть равен 44, но у меня не получается, т.к. G18 больше 20, что противоречит условию задания.

Прикрепляю все формулы с их координатами:

C5 = A5-1

D5, D13 = B5

C9, C17 = A5

C13 = ЕСЛИ(ОСТАТ(A5;2)=0;A5/2;A5/2+0,5)

D17 = ЕСЛИ(ОСТАТ(B5;2)=0;B5/2;B5/2+0,5)

(Далее по такому же принципу действую до G)

G5 = ЕСЛИ(ОСТАТ(МАКС(E5:F5); 2) = 0; МАКС(E5:F5) / 2; МАКС(E5:F5) / 2 + 0,5)   + МИН(E5:F5)

Р5 = E5+F5

(Далее скопировал просто вниз)

Клетки подсвечиваются зеленым в столбце G при условии значения <= 20

Также столбец проверки(столбец H)  должен быть больше 20 по условию задания

Comment: Вы бы лучше живой файл показали

Comment: Как это сделать, как прикрепить файл к сообщению?